# Пример многопоточного разделения файла на несколько частей

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Подскажите пример правильного применения thread, для моей задачи. Задача заключается в параллельном разбиении файла на несколько частей.

Делаю следующим образом, уже посчитано кол-во частей для файла. После этого вызываю метод для создания части из файла в новом потоке, кол-во потоков будет = количеству частей файла, то есть под каждое новое создание части будет отдельный поток.

```
for (int i = 0; i < countOfParts; i++)
{                        
    thread = new Thread(CreateFileParts);
    thread.Start(i);
}

 void CreateFileParts(object i)
        {               
            try
            {
                lock (locked)
                {
                    using (FileStream fsRead = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        //for (int i = 0; i < countOfParts; i++)
                        {
                            using (FileStream fsWrite = new FileStream(@"parts\" + $"{i}_{fileName}", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            {
                                if ((int)i == countOfParts - 1)
                                {
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeLastPart];
                                    fsRead.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                    fsWrite.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfOnePart];
                                    fsRead.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                    fsWrite.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }                       
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }              
        }
```

Файл успешно делится, но когда его составляю в исходный, он получается неправильный. Например если я разбил некое видео на части и потом эти части совместил, то видео получается битым, воспроизводится только та часть байтов, которая была в первой разделенного файла.

Без потоков все выполняется отлично. Подскажите, как можно сделать иначе или помогите исправить мой пример.

Comment: Вы же можете в hex редаторе сравнить файлы и посмотреть, чем они отличаются. Может быть вы склеиваете их не правильно например.

Comment: Я же написал, что слияние правильное без деления на потоки

Comment: Хотя судя по вашему коду, необходимо добавить смещение, т.е. 2 часть вы должны читать не с начала файла, а со смещением в равным размеру первой части. У вас я не вижу смещения.

Comment: Это метод, который просто делит файл на части. Он никак не относится к методу для получения исходного файла из частей

Comment: Создайте простенький текстовый файл. Поделите его, посмотрите сами правильно ли он поделился.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Подскажите пример правильного применения thread, для моей задачи.

Правильный пример — **не использовать** потоки для вашей задачи.

Железо устроено таким образом, что читать файл последовательно — это самая эффективная операция с диском, независимо от того, SSD это или HDD. Если разбивать чтение на потоки, то вы будете только **замедлять** чтение. Более того, если вы читаете с HDD огромный файл, то при использовании двух потоков скорость может значительно уменьшиться, потому что головке диска придётся бегать из одного положения в другое. **Чем больше потоков, тем медленнее операция чтения**.

Единственный случай, когда чтение и запись можно выполнять параллельно — это если чтение происходит с одного диска, а запись ведётся на другой. Если это не ваш случай, то прекратите пытаться добавить потоки.

Если это ваш случай, то можно воспользоваться `await Task.WhenAll(readTask, writeTask)`, наверное. Впрочем, возможно, даже самый простой код для копирования будет работать достаточно эффективно, потому что операционная система умеет предсказывать последовательное чтение и прекрасно оптимизирует доступ — и в этом случае самый простой код будет плюсом, а не минусом.

Answer (score 3):

Вам уже сказали, что смещения нет.

Судя по коду, ваше последовательное чтение выглядит так:

```
using (FileStream fsRead = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   for (int i = 0; i < countOfParts; i++)
   {
      using (FileStream fsWrite = new FileStream(@"parts\" + $"{i}_{fileName}", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
      {
         if ((int)i == countOfParts - 1)
         {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeLastPart];
            fsRead.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fsWrite.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         }
         else
         {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfOnePart];
            fsRead.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fsWrite.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Он работает, потому что после открытия файла вы его читаете подряд не закрывая и позиция чтения смещается. То есть смотрите, что происходит:

1. Вы открыли файл. Курсор на позиции 0.
2. Вы прочли N-ое количество байт и записали. Курсор на позиции N.
3. Вы ещё раз прочли N-ое количество байт. Курсор на позиции N+N.
4. И т.д.

В случае многопоточности у вас позиция чтения всегда в нуле:

1. Открыли файл. Курсор на позиции 0.
2. Прочли N-ое количество байт и записали. Курсор на позиции N.
3. Закрыли файл.

То есть ваш многопоточный код читает всегда **одно и то же**.

Если исправлять ваш код, то можно сделать так:

```
using (FileStream fsRead = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   fsRead.Position = i * sizeOfOnePart;
   using (FileStream fsWrite = new FileStream(@"parts\" + $"{i}_{fileName}", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
      {
```

Но как уже сказали: параллельное чтение файлов - дело затратное.